# PhoneGap Contacts - Add Custom ims(social profile)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, cordova

Hello I'm trying to save custom social profile names to the contacts database on ios and android using phonegap contacts api.

I can save ims okay, but the problem is with the field names, which are always "IM_SERVICE_NAME" instead of "Custom" "Skype" or "MSN Messenger".Following is the code that I have used:

```
 var ims = [];
 ims[0] = new ContactField('skype', 'raj');
 contact.ims = ims;
 contact.save();
```

It would be great if anyone could help me out on this. I'm really struggling to find any solutions.THANKS

Comment: Hey! any update on your question? I am interested on that too